# Error syntax about AddComment to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

What's wrong with my syntax here?

```
If Range("K15") = "01/11/2015" Then
    Range("B15").AddComment ("Workbooks("James").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are intended to display the value from workbook "James", you could try the following:

```
Sub test()

Dim msg As String
msg = Workbooks("James").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value

If Range("K15") = "01/11/2015" Then
    Range("B15").AddComment (msg)

End If
End Sub
```

Or simply remove the double quote around the whole Addcommand's argument.